# Display the string 4 times and shuffle the 3 and retain the original string

Tags: php

How do you display a string 4x and shuffle the 3 duplicate string and retaining the original string.

for example 
SAMPLE AMSPLE PLESAM ELSAMP 
ADTA DATA, TADA, ADAT

Something like this?

Here is my codes.

```
$words = array('SAMPLE', 'DATA');

    foreach ($words as $wrd) 
        {

        for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
            {
                echo str_shuffle($wrd);
                echo '&nbsp';
            }   
            echo '<br/>';   
        }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with that code?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Echo the original word inside the foreach, but outside the for, and loop your for loop only 3 times.

Comment: Why does the second line of the example have the original string second instead of first?

Comment: @andrewsi well this codes only display shuffle letter of the strings, cant find a way to insert the correct string

Comment: @user2901740 Put `echo $wrd` before the `for` loop.

Comment: @tigrang is it possible to randomly do that?

Comment: @user2901740 - can't you just `echo($wrd)` at the end of your for loop?

Comment: BTW, you're missing the `;` after `&nbsp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put the original word into a random position among the shuffled versions:

```
$words = array('SAMPLE', 'DATA');

foreach ($words as $wrd) {
    $array = array($wrd);
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
        $array[] = str_shuffle($wrd);
    }
    shuffle($array);
    echo implode("&nbsp;", $array);
    echo '<br/>';   
}
```

Comment: This works, randomly insert the correct word in the shuffle strings,

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = array('SAMPLE', 'DATA');

foreach ($words as $wrd) 
    {
        echo $wrd
        echo '&nbsp';
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
        {
            echo str_shuffle($wrd);
            echo '&nbsp';
        }   
        echo '<br/>';   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A as others have said, just loop 3 times and echo the original `$wrd` before you loop the other 3 times when you shuffle it.

If we're on the first loop echo the real word, else shuffle it.

```
$words = array('SAMPLE', 'DATA');

foreach ($words as $wrd) 
  {
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
      {

        if ($i == 1)
          {
            echo $wrd;
           }
        else
          {
            echo str_shuffle($wrd);
           }

        echo '&nbsp';

       }   

     echo '<br/>';   
  }
```

If you want this to be random, then you'll have to set a new var to a random var between 1 and 4, and then use that random var to determine if the current loop number (`$i`) is equal to the random one you created.

I haven't given this code as it's fairly easy to research and have a go yourself, post back if you get stuck.

Comment: I already done this but didnt work. It display the first correct word and shuffle the rest

Comment: Why didn't work? That's exactly what it's supposed to do. He explained how you can modify it if you want the correct word in a random place instead of first.

Comment: It should work fine. If not you need to say why in detail, so I can advise :) You have a perfect answer from Barmar anyway.